# PNG image handler not found

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

following piece of code is not able to save a PNG file:

```
wxBitmap screenshot(screenWidth,screenHeight,24);
...
::wxInitAllImageHandlers();
screenshot.SaveFile(path,wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
```

Although I added all image handlers (and when I step through wxInitAllImageHandlers() I can see even the PNG handler is added), the call to SaveFile() fails to save my bitmap as png file. When I step through the code of SaveFile(), I can see, there is no image handler for PNG, only five simple types are available.

So...what am I doing wrong here? How can I wxBitmap encourage to save PNG files?

Comment: what wx version? What platform? Does the image saved or not?

Comment: This is definitely "impossible" (unless you explicitly disabled PNG support during the build, but you wouldn't have been asking about it if you did this, presumably), which means that you must have triggered some kind of undefined behaviour somewhere else. One hypothesis is that you somehow ended up using multiple copies of wx libraries. But, whatever it is, it's something outside of this snippet -- if you insert it into wx minimal sample, you can will surely see that it works successfully.

Comment: @VZ. not impossible but exactly the behaviour I see. I solved it by convertign the wxBitmap to a wxImage and then use the function SaveFile() of that wxImage - there the PNG image handler can be found and the image is saved properly and as expected

Comment: To [paraphrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagan_standard), when making extraordinary claims, at least some (let alone extraordinary) evidence is required. If you could reproduce the problem in a [simple example](http://sscce.org/), it would be one thing, but without it there is not much to say.